# Get Category ID from Product UPC

Tags: ebay-api

I would like to know that if there is any ebay API call which takes input of UPC number and return their respective ebay category ID e.g.(177) or category hierarchy (Computers/Tablets & Networking > Laptops & Netbooks > PC Laptops & Netbooks)? 
Thanks in advance. 
Regards, 
Arshad P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the findITemByProduct call from the finding api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<findItemsByProductRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<productId type="UPC">xxxxxxxxxxx(upc number)</productId>
</findItemsByProductRequest>
```

This would return the product data and you can get the categoryId and name from this.